# Regex: need an alternative for positive lookbehind

Tags: regex, logging, lookbehind, graylog

I have a regex that searches for IP addresses in a log file. I am using positive lookbehind for this. I want to get IP addresses in a line that contains `phpExecution`. My regex is

```
(?<=.*sqlExecution.*"ip":")[^"]+
```

The problem is that the log analyzing tool that we are using (graylog) does not support lookbehinds. This regex works in VSCode search and online regex testers. But in the graylog, it does not work.

is there any alternative for this regex without the lookbehind?

Sample log line:

`<200> Nov 16 14:36:10 phpExecution INFO: Php Execution {"ip":"33.333.333.33","workspace":"gasqazvin","timeZone":"2019-11-16 14:11:10","usrUid":"","action":"phpExecution","filename":"/var/www/html/pm/shared/sites/work/public/1244635345345/23425452.php","url":"/syswork/fa/modern/1244635345345/23425452.php?"}`

It's not just IP field, I have to do it for all the fields, like `workflow`, `timezone`, ... . So it might not be just digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this pattern `phpExecution.+"ip":\s*"([^"]+)`

Explanation:

`phpExecution` - match `phpExecution` literally

`.+` - 1+ of any chars

`"ip":` - match `"ip":` literally

`\s*` - 0+ of whitespaces

`"([^"]+)` - match `"` literally, then 1+ chars other from `"` and store it in **first capturing group** - this will be your desired value

Note that you can put any field name in place of `ip`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lbCIrb/1)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer :). I tried this, it kinda works but the problem is it returns all the words from phpexecution to ip address. `phpExecution INFO: Php Execution {"ip":"46.101.167.63`

Comment: Get only first capruted group - this is why I used it :)

Comment: Oh I see it, can you help me how to do it? There no place to use any code snippets in graylog, only a regex field and return type. I am new to regex, Thanks

Comment: @ArashMohammadi Just google "greylog regex capturing groups". I have not ever used graylog, so I can't help any further.

Comment: Looks like the server was down. That was the reason for not returning the result. You regex works perfect. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution:

```
\"ip\":\"([^\"]+)\".+\"action\":\"phpExecution\".+
```

With the following assumption: `phpExecution` is always after the IP address in the JSON

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/6rJcia/1

Note that I would suggest to use a JSON parser for this job.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer :)., The ip is after the phpExecustion. I can't use json parser. there is only regex in graylog

Comment: Is this always the same order ? In your sample "ip" is before "phpExecution"

Comment: Yes , ip is after the phpExecution.